# Where can I find shared drives on my file server?

Tags: windows, server, sharing, file-sharing

I'm new to a company with a small network of computers (~10). We have a server (\\SERVER) that has multiple shared folders on it. The image below is a snapshot from file explorer. The bottom left shows "Network" and "server" appearing on the network. The shared files are also shown.

When I am logged into the SERVER (i.e. sit down at the actual computer acting as the server) with an administrator account, I can't find these shared folders anywhere. I suspect they reside somewhere on the C: drive (both the C: drive and the shared folders have the exact same size). My question is, where should I be able to find these folders on the computer SERVER?

I am definitely a noob to this type of thing. Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental. Either way, any help that could be offered would be very appreciated!

[image: shared folders on SERVER]

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More info is available in the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To view a list of all shared folders**

1. Right-click `Computer` and choose `Manage` (Requires administrative
   privileges)
2. Once opened, go to `Computer Management` > `System
   Tools` > `Shared Folders` > `Shares`

[image: Screenshot]

Note: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. You can ask this kind of question in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) since it is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the note about superuser.com. I'll remember that going forward.

Comment: @RyanJames, Thank you & It's a pleasure to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a command shell and type:

net share

Comment: Wish I could accept both answers. This provides the same information too! Thanks!

Comment: glad that I was able to help you, Ryan.